# Php: Session not working correctly

Tags: php

i have code:

```
$search = $_REQUEST['search'];

if(!isset($_REQUEST['search'])){
    if(is_null($_SESSION['ss_search']))
        $search = 0;
    else
        $search = $_SESSION['ss_search'];
}

$_SESSION['ss_search']=$search;

echo $_SESSION['ss_search'];
```

firstly I enter number 1 and submit, browser return 1. Then I enter number 2 and submit, browser return 2 but I refresh browser, it return 1. I don't know why session stored value 2 but when refresh it return old value. i used **session_start()** on top.

Comment: You're question is not pretty clear. What method are you using to post your form ? Have you debug `$_REQUEST['search']` each refresh ?

Comment: i using post method? my problem is why session stored new value but return old value.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code

```
  $search = $_REQUEST['search'];

  $_SESSION['ss_search']=$search;

  echo $_SESSION['ss_search'];
```

Try this and let me know.

Comment: Refreshing your page means you are not submitting it? Have you tried the above code?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but try to remove (NOT)! from the if statement. It worked for me.

change

```
if(!isset($_REQUEST['search'])){
```

to

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['search'])){
```

Please let me know if you face any problem.

Comment: no, if(!isset($_REQUEST['search'])) just check i have submited, if i not submit example i refresh browser. so i think that code is right

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code and amend it as following:

```
 $search ="";
if(!isset($_REQUEST['search'])){
if(is_null($_SESSION['ss_search']))
    $search = 0;
else
    $search = $_SESSION['ss_search'];
}else{
$search=$_REQUEST['search'];
}

$_SESSION['ss_search']=$search;

echo $_SESSION['ss_search'];
```

using `$_REQUEST['search']` without checking if it is set, cause it to generate undefined index notice. so now `$_REQUEST['search']` is called only when it is set, Another cause is if you have set the default value on your form input field equal to 1, and when you refresh the page and allow it to resend the form, it may send the default value of your form.